# Why does xpathSApply (XML-package) used in a function throw an error when used with lapply

Tags: r, xpath

Here is my function:

```
# Purpose: Scrape Floraweb.de for plant species data (photograph, sociology, ecology, anatomy)
# Author: Kay Cichini
# Date: 2012-06-10
# Output: PDF saved to created folder .~/FLORAWEB
# Packages: XML, jpeg, 
# Licence: cc by-nc-sa

floraweb_scraper <- function(input) {

    # I didn't get around this encoding issue other than with gsub..
    spch_sub <- function(x) {
        x <- gsub("Ã¼", "ü", x)
        x <- gsub("Ã¤", "ä", x)
        x <- gsub("Ã¶", "ö", x)
        x <- gsub("Ã„", "Ä", x)
        x <- gsub("Ãoe", "Ü", x)
        x <- gsub("Ã¼", "Ä", x)
        x <- gsub("Ã–", "Ö", x)
        x <- gsub("ÃŸ", "ß", x)
        x <- gsub("Ã©", "é", x)
        x <- gsub("Ã-", "í", x)
        x <- gsub("Ã¡", "á", x)
        x <- gsub("Â±", "~", x)
        x <- gsub("Â ", "", x)  # pattern for backspaces
    }

    # automated package installation:
    pkgs <- c("XML", "jpeg")

    pkgs_miss <- pkgs[which(!pkgs %in% installed.packages()[, 1])]
    if (length(pkgs_miss) > 0) {
        install.packages(pkgs_miss)
    }

    # load packages:
    require(XML)
    require(jpeg)


    # prepare input and get parsed script:
    input1 <- gsub("[[:space:]]", "+", input)
    URL <- paste("http://www.floraweb.de/pflanzenarten/taxoquery.xsql?taxname=", 
                 input1, sep = "")
    doc <- htmlParse(URL)

    # get returned species names (dismiss last row with additional info):
    sp <- xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@id='contentblock']//a", xmlValue)
    sp <- sp[1:length(sp)-1]

    # get species ids from contentblock:
    con <- getNodeSet(doc, "//div[@id='contentblock']//a")[1:len]
    urls <- sapply(con, xmlGetAttr, "href")
    id_1 <- gsub("[^0-9]", "", urls)

    # check matching and assign to resulting dataframe:
    match <- numeric()
    for (i in 1:len) {
        match[i] <- sum(unlist(strsplit(tolower(sp), " ")[i]) %in% unlist(strsplit(input, 
            " ")) == 0)
    }
    df <- data.frame(sp, id_1, match)

    # select the one with best match:
    sel <- id_1[rank(df$match)][1]

    # build urls for retrieving species data
    url <- paste("http://www.floraweb.de/pflanzenarten/druck.xsql?suchnr=", sel, sep = "")

    doc <- htmlParse(url)
    img_src <- xpathSApply(doc, '//*/p[@class="centeredcontent"]/img/@src')
    img_url <- gsub("../", "http://www.floraweb.de/", img_src, fixed = T)

    # get infos:
    infos <- xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@id='content']//p", xmlValue)[c(2, 7, 22, 33, 35, 14)]

    # replace special characters:
    infos <- spch_sub(infos)

    # make dir to save data:
    dir.create(path.expand("~/FLORAWEB/"), showWarnings = F)
    setwd(path.expand("~/FLORAWEB/"))

    # download image:
    download.file(img_url, "floraweb.jpg", mode = "wb")

    # open device:
    pdf(paste(spch_sub(df$sp[df$id_1 == sel]), ".FloraWeb.pdf", sep = ""), paper = "a4")

    # read image:
    img <- readJPEG("floraweb.jpg")
    w <- dim(img)[2]
    h <- dim(img)[1]

    # print img to plot region:
    par(mar = rep(0, 4), oma = rep(0, 4), mfrow = c(2, 1))
    plot(NA, xlim = c(0, w), ylim = c(0, h), xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = F, 
    type = "n", yaxs = "i", xaxs = "i", asp = 1)
    rasterImage(img, 0, 0, w, h)

    # print text:
    plot(NA, xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1), xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = F, type = "n", 
        yaxs = "i", xaxs = "i")
    # text left intendent and center adjustment:
    l <- 0.5
    c_adj <- c(0.5, 0.5)

    # plot text:
    text(l, 0.95, paste("Eingabe = ", input, " / Gefunden = ", infos[1], sep = ""), font = 2, adj = c_adj, cex = 0.7)
    text(l, 0.5, paste(strwrap(infos[-1], width = 112), collapse = "\n"), adj = c_adj, cex = 0.7)

    # Credit:
    text(l, 0.05, "Die hier verwendeten Daten sind der Internet-Seite FloraWeb.de entnommen.", 
        adj = c_adj, cex = 0.4, font = 3)

    graphics.off()
    message(paste(sp_name, "PDF wurde erzeugt\n\n", sep = "\n -- "))

    # remove jpegs:
    unlink(dir(pattern = ".jpg"))
}

# Examples:
floraweb_scraper("Poa alp")

pfl_liste <- c("leuc alp", "Poa badensis", "Poa alp")
lapply(pfl_liste, FUN = floraweb_scraper)
```

It works well in the first example but throws error when used with lapply -
does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

object `len` is undefined

```
for (i in 1:len) {
        match[i] <- sum(unlist(strsplit(tolower(sp), " ")[i]) %in% unlist(strsplit(input, 
            " ")) == 0)
    }
```

you probably have it defined in your workspace. When you call the first function everything is ok. Maybe you have problems with scope when using `lapply`. Defining `len` in your function may resolve matters

Comment: Your right - embarrassingly I oversaw some undefined variables after editing the file..